# how to match only the two first hosts from host file

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

with the following egrep command I get the hosts from the /etc/hosts file as the following example

```
egrep "Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware" /etc/hosts

192.9.200.12 Solaris1
192.9.200.13 Solaris2
192.9.200.14 Solaris3
192.9.200.15 Solaris4
192.9.200.16 Solaris5
192.9.200.17 linux1
192.9.200.18 linux2
192.9.200.19 linux3 
192.9.200.20 linux4
192.9.200.21 linux5
```

what I want is to add  awk or sed or perl one liner command that will print only the two first match hosts as the following

```
egrep "Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware" | ...... /etc/hosts

192.9.200.12 Solaris1
192.9.200.13 Solaris2
192.9.200.17 linux1
192.9.200.18 linux2
```

Comment: sample show OS with ending index, is it always starting at 1 than 2 or this is pure sample (can we assume that filter is based on OS + `1` or `2` ) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -ne'
  print if /(Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware)/ && ++$s{$1}<=2;
' /etc/hosts
```

output

```
192.9.200.12 Solaris1
192.9.200.13 Solaris2
192.9.200.17 linux1
192.9.200.18 linux2
```

Comment: What does `++$s{$1}` do ?

Comment: I don't really know much perl, i understand the `++` as it is used in quite a few languages. I more wanted to know what `$s{$1}` is, is it the result of the `if` before ?

Comment: @Jidder `$1` is first captured group from regex and used as key in `%s` hash.

Comment: cheers, i really need to get round to learning perl. Nice answer as well btw!

Comment: @Jidder if you're interested check http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes among other (short and straight to the point) articles.

Comment: thanks again, that looks like a really good site to start on.

Answer (score 2):

by awk

```
awk '/Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware/{a=$2;sub(/[0-9]*$/,"",a); if (++b[a]<=2) print}' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk way

```
awk '
     match($0,/Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware/,a)&&++b[a[0]]<=2
' file
```

#### Explanation

Matches the the list of names and stores in variable `a` (this does not include the number after).
And then increments another array `b` with the name `a[0]` and checks if less than 2
Default action for awk is print

VOILA

```
192.9.200.12 Solaris1
192.9.200.13 Solaris2
192.9.200.17 linux1
192.9.200.18 linux2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{t=$2; sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",t)} /Solaris|linux|unix|vms|win|proxy|terminal|unixware/ && ++cnt[t] <= 2' /etc/hosts | sort
```

**Logic:**

variable `t` will hold the modified last field (eg: Solaris1 => Solaris, Solaris2 => Solaris, linux1 => linux, linux3 => linux etc...) if current line matches the pattern, and less than 2 matches found already, print the line... In the end `sort` if required.